# Webpack compiler instance promisification?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, bluebird

I'm using the [Webpack 2 Node API](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/) and I would like to promisify the `run()` method using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html).

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import webpack from 'webpack'

const compiler = webpack(config)
const runAsync = Promise.promisify(compiler.run)

runAsync().then(stats => {
  console.log('stats:', stats)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('err:', err)
})
```

The error I'm getting is:

> [TypeError: self.applyPluginsAsync is not a function]

So I'm guessing that the webpack code isn't written in a way that's compatible with bluebird promisification.

If there any other way to promisify webpack's `run()` method..?

All these callbacks and `if` statements are bugging me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `compiler` as the context to the `promisify` method.

```
const runAsync = Promise.promisify(compiler.run, { context: compiler });
```

Or call it like so:

```
runAsync.call(compiler).then(stats => {...
```

From the Bluebird [Docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html):

> Note that if the node function is a method of some object, you can pass the object as the second argument like so:

```
var redisGet = Promise.promisify(redisClient.get, {context: redisClient});
redisGet('foo').then(function() {
    //...
});
```